How to populate a master table from multiple data queries in Excel using Excel's Python integration
I'm attempting to analyze some NFL player data in Excel and I'm having trouble cleaning my data. I'm pulling player stats from profootballreference.com using Data queries and trying to compile them into game logs. I'd like to use Excel's python integration to achieve this, but if there's a more efficient approach, please let me know. I've attached photos from the skeleton of my workbook below. In the Running Back Game Log sheet, you can see I've attempted to populate the opponent column, but clearly my python fluency is weak LOL. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.
sample data query (Saquon Barkley)
code for converting to dataframe:
Saquon_Barkley = xl("Saquon_Barkley[#All]", headers=True)

Skeleton of Master Game Log Table (Note shite python syntax for opponent data)
for loop to populate master table:
for opp in Saquon_Barkley['Opponents']:
    print(opp)

I tried making the data query into a data frame, then using a for loop to print each item in a column into my master game log table.

You could try Saquan_Barkley['Opponents'] to get the complete column. To get the first two rows in Opponents column, Saquan_Barkley['Opponents'].iloc[:2] .

Why not just straight up use python, do the data cleansing in python. Then when done, simply write to excel, as opposed to having excel run python scripts?

When you use python in an excel cell, excel can only display a single value in that cell.  That single value will be the python code's return value. I don't believe that you can display a series of values into multiple cells using excel's python feature.
